# Android WebView crash on Back press twice

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView, which crashes if I double press the Back button when the view can go Back. What happens, is that on first Back press, it causes the page to go back (which causes the loading of the previous page (Page A). Then the second onKeyDown event comes and kills the WebView (as expected). The problem is that after the WebView is already killed, the page A continues to load (due to the first press on the Back button), and its onPageStarted and onPageFinished are called. These functions crash the application, as the webView is already destroyed. What can I do?

```
  @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if (page.canGoBack()) {
                            progressBar.stopProgressAnimation();
                            page.goBack();
                            return true;
                        } else {        
                            exitGracefully();
                        }
                }

            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

private void exitGracefully() {
        destroyWebview();
        navigationBarLayout.recycleViewBitmaps();
        getActivity().finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keycode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (view.canGoBack()) {
                    view.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, event);
}
}
```

This is worked in my case add 'return true;' statement in switch case ....

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help. The onPageFinished and onPageStarted is still called after the webView is detroyed

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        try{

            //your code here

        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        try{

            //your code here
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
```

This worked for me. Use try catch in onPageStarted() and onPageFinished().
I think this works for you also, try it.